# Add g tag into svg tag without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

I have svg element from this code

```
let chartSVG = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refChart).children[0];
```

I want to add a watermark contain g tag into that chartSVG.

Comment: Just `createElementNS()` and `appendChild()`, no?

Comment: Could you give me some code?

Answer (score 2):

Should be basic DOM manipulation using [`createElementNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) and [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

```js
const xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

const rect = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'rect');
rect.setAttributeNS (null, "width", 50);
rect.setAttributeNS (null, "height", 50);

const g = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'g');
g.appendChild(rect);

const svg = document.getElementById('svg');
svg.appendChild(g);
```

```html
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

Or, if you have your SVG content as a string, you can use a [`DOMParser()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and import the fragment:

```js
const g = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
   '<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect width="50" height="50"/></g>',
   'application/xml');

const svg = document.getElementById('svg');
svg.appendChild(svg.ownerDocument.importNode(g.documentElement, true));
```

```html
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

Comment: Hi @Robby, thanks for your answer, but my <g> tag contain nested <g> tag, so do I need to appendChild g tag into g tag?

Comment: Yes indeed. Need to build up the entire tree. Or just import from string.

Comment: I used parseFromString to parse something like this: `<g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">` but I got error in some "".

Comment: Need a xmlns attribute in your root g element.